# Does sed have a feature superior to awk?

Tags: awk, sed

Recently I learned `sed` for a while and it was awkward experience due to

- need of remembering single-letter commands (`p`, `a`, `d`, ...)
- concept of ***single*** hold space for remembering the context – controlled by other similar commands (`h`, `x`, `g`, ...)

I said to myself: couldn't this be made more intuitive? I.e. with more verbose commands (e.g. `print` instead of `p`) and more than *one* buffer – standard variables according to my need (e.g. `lastUserSeen`)?

And then someone [told me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44532359/filter-only-certain-categories-of-log-records-using-sed#comment76088303_44533002):

> No, **never** use `h` or any other sed constructs except s, g, and p (with -n) or you are literally using constructs that became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented. People use those other constructs today strictly for the mental exercise, not to seriously write software, since an equivalent awk solution will be clearer, more efficient, more portable, easier to maintain/enhance, and better in every other meaningful way.

awk? I immediately jumped on and fell in love with it. Many of my multi-line programs worked on first run, without any debugging. From what I since then studied about the awk, I think it is able to completely supersede the sed. Or **is there some sed feature (which I missed) effect of which cannot be easily achieved by the awk?** Is there any reason why an awk user would run sed?

Edit: this is not a question "which is better", but a comparison of feature sets. Is there a feature in sed effect of which cannot be achieved similarly efficiently in awk, but it would need much more awk code?

Comment: This is like useless discussion about one programming language over another, one editor over another, one distribution over another and so on. `sed` has pros and cons like `awk`, `perl` or `python` have. If you know to handle different tools, you can choose the best for a specific problem. The simple concept of `sed` and single char commands can be view as advantage for quick, compact scripts. You see it as disadvantage. So this is mainly opinion based.

Comment: Similar: [When to use grep, less, awk, sed](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/303044)

Comment: @Philippos – I think you misunderstood the question. Please see the edit. Someone can still view discontinued Symbian OS way better than today's Android, and I will not go into these religious wars. I am interested in comparison of features because there could be some obvious non-equivalencies. The answers can point to them from programmers' viewpoint, which is technically more exact. `sed -i` is a good example, because it cannot be equivalently efficiently implemented in awk without in-place editing extension.

Comment: I've learned a lot of `awk` from Ed but his comment over there is _waaaay off_... Any seasoned `sed` user will tell you that statement is BS. `sed` is just as portable as `awk` and just as easy to maintain if the maintainer is equally proficient with both of them. And never use `h`,`x`,`d` etc ? Such comments are usually made by people who cannot fully understand how `sed` operates on a stream of data. Try doing something like `sed '$d'` or `sed 'x;$!d'` with `awk`, see if you can make it "more efficient" or golf it shorter. Each has its pros and cons so yes, this is primarily opinion based.

Comment: @don_crissti – you are following Ed's comment, but you seem to ignore the question in bold letters and clarifications following it. I see it works a a red cape making some readers ignoring the point. At least some people got it right and posted answers addressing exactly what I was asking.   If I remove Ed's statement, will you remove the hold status?

Comment: No. You seem to have a hard time understanding that any answer to your question (in bold) _will be opinion based_. And by the way, options like `-i` for editing files in place are a completely different thing (and btw, as pointed out below, `gnu awk` has this ability). Your question (just like Ed's comment) seems to be about the ability of each tool to process text (and its efficiency/ease of use etc).

Comment: @don_crissti – just to clarify: if you show that `sed 'x;$!d'` needs at least three lines in awk to do the same, is this opinion-based? But showing this as asnwer will be exactly the way of how I can learn that in which typical cases awk's feaures don't match sed's.

Comment: Yes, because then Ed Morton will come up with an `awk` one liner example which is the equivalent of 11 `sed` commands ;) ... lol, come on man, can't you see it all depends on the input, the task at hand and the human operator ? Read, learn, practice, get better and you will know when to use one and when to use the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a quick and easy way to edit a file in place, `sed` -i feature is a whole lot easier than constructing something similar using `awk`.  I accept that platforms using `gawk` at version 1.4.0 or later do have the "inplace" feature to cover this.

```
sed -i 's/foo/bar/' filename
```

Reluctantly learned `sed` myself due to all the existing scripts using it.  Given a choice, when writing a new script, `awk` usually wins, the code is so much more readable + maintainable.

Comment: `sed -i` is a GNU `sed` extension. GNU `awk` has a similar extension (`awk -i inplace`).

Comment: Interesting find. So the `-i` will save me sequence of two additional commands, correct? I mean that without `-i` I have to *(0) put processing result into temp file instead of original file (1) delete original file (2) rename temp file to original file.*

Comment: Indeed.  Bang on !